# Awk - sort data inside program - custom datetime stamp

Tags: awk

I am using gawk to process a large text file.  I now have a need to sort a column in the file.  Is it possible to use gawk to sort on a column that contains a datetime stamp?

The datetime stamp shown in column 2 is "`m/d/yy, H:M AM/PM`" in double quotes.

```
1,”2/1/22, 9:25 AM",
2,"2/8/22, 11:03 AM",
3,"2/7/22, 8:57 AM",
4,"2/18/22, 5:50 PM",
5,"2/24/22, 9:11 AM",
6,"2/7/22, 1:59 PM",
7,"2/9/22, 7:34 AM",
8,"2/16/22, 7:14 AM",
9,"1/31/22, 5:53 PM",
```

Can I sort that data in gawk, so I can insert a third column and have my table as

```
9,"1/31/22, 5:53 PM",1
1,”2/1/22, 9:25 AM",2
3,"2/7/22, 8:57 AM",3
6,"2/7/22, 1:59 PM",4
2,"2/8/22, 11:03 AM",5
7,"2/9/22, 7:34 AM",6
8,"2/16/22, 7:14 AM",7
4,"2/18/22, 5:50 PM",8
5,"2/24/22, 9:11 AM",9
```

Is this possible in gawk?

Comment: *a large text file* is said file bigger than RAM available to you or it will fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the size of the file does not exceed the available memory, would you please try:

```
gawk '
    # custom function to compare the timestamps
    function date_sort(i1, v1, i2, v2,     a1, a2, s1, s2) {
        split(v1, a1, /[,"/: ]+/)
        split(v2, a2, /[,"/: ]+/)
        # generate strings of "yy-mm-dd (AM|PM) hh:mm"
        s1 = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d %s %02d:%02d",
                a1[4], a1[2], a1[3], a1[7], a1[5], a1[6])
        s2 = sprintf("%02d-%02d-%02d %s %02d:%02d",
                a2[4], a2[2], a2[3], a2[7], a2[5], a2[6])
        # return the comparison result
        if (s1 < s2) {
            return -1
        } else if (s1 > s2) {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    # read the file and store lines in an array "data"
    {data[NR] = $0}
    END {
        # sort "data" using the function "date_sort" and store the result in "sorted"
        n = asort(data, sorted, "date_sort")
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            print sorted[i] i
        }
    }
' input_file
```

Output:

```
9,"1/31/22, 5:53 PM",1
1,"2/1/22, 9:25 AM",2
3,"2/7/22, 8:57 AM",3
6,"2/7/22, 1:59 PM",4
2,"2/8/22, 11:03 AM",5
7,"2/9/22, 7:34 AM",6
8,"2/16/22, 7:14 AM",7
4,"2/18/22, 5:50 PM",8
5,"2/24/22, 9:11 AM",9
```

The 3rd argument `"date_sort"` to the `asort` function is a custom function name
to compare the list to sort. The function should be designed to return a negative value, a positive value, or zero depending on the
comparison of passed two elements. Four arguments are implicitly passed to the function during the sort operation:
index of the element of the 1st list, value of the element of the 1st list,
index of the element of the 2nd list, value of the element of the 2nd list, in order.
I have named them `i1`, `v1`, `i2`, `v2`, by convention.

The remaining variables `a1`, `a2`, `s1`, `s2` are the local variables.
It is a feature of `awk` that the variable list which is longer than the number
of arguments passed by the caller is used to declare local variable names to limit
the scope of the variables within the function.

Comment: Could you explain the signature of the date_sort(i1, v1, i2, v2,     a1, a2, s1, s2)?    What are the arguments and why does signature exactly that number of arguments?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer with a brief explanation about the `asort` function and the arguments passed to the comparison function. I hope it explains well. BR.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.